# python subprocess.Popen: mpv fails to play video URL, works in shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, youtube-api

(host operating system is OS X 10.10, Python version is 2.7.6)

I have a function in a Python program that uses youtube-dl to get a a direct video URL of a YouTube video.

```
mpv_executable = find_executable("mpv")
if mpv_executable is None:
    raise RuntimeError('mpv not found')

get_api_url = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl', '-g', url], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
ytapi_url,ec = get_api_url.communicate()
print(ytapi_url)
player = subprocess.Popen([mpv_executable, '--really-quiet', ytapi_url], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
player.wait()
```

If I remove the stdout/stderr parts from the second last line, I can see that mpv fails to play the video:

> Failed to open https://r19---sn-npo7ene7.googlevideo.com/[...]

However, if I copy the URL mpv attempts to play, and then do the following in the shell (pbpaste outputs the contents of the clipboard, if you are unaware of OS X-specific shell utilities):

> $ mpv "$(pbpaste)"

mpv plays the video without any issues.

Comment: It's not _likely_, but it's _possible_ that mpv is failing because you've blocked its pipes by not reading from them. Try using `player.communicate()` instead of `player.wait()`. Or, if you really don't want its `stdout` and `stderr`, while capture them to a pipe? Just use `subprocess.DEVNULL` or something.

Comment: @abarnert I tried using `player.wait()`, and the issue remains.

Comment: My suggestion was to try _not_ using `player.wait()`. Your posted code already uses it, and that's an unlikely, but possible cause of problems like this.

Comment: Whoops, meant to say I used `player.communicate()` there. I do know for sure that I tested `player.communicate()` as you suggested.